# "A lead man" vs. "lead man"

Tags: articles

> - Sam will be lead man of my team.

If lead man is a noun phrase, why isn't it preceded by an article to turn into " a lead man" or "the lead man"?

Comment: Because in some contexts, the article is optional, not required.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, "lead man" is a [False Title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_title).

Although it is a widely-use construction, it is arguably better to include an article particularly in British English.

Titles do not take an article while the name of a position does.  For example in "Rufus is **the** President of Freedonia.", *President of Freedonia* is the name of the position and requires an article while in "Rufus is President of Freedonia.", *President of Freedonia* is Rufus's title and does not need an article.